# Create a rectangle around a binary image mask

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

From a given image i'm able to create a binary mask that detect certain objects, how i can draw multiple rectangles a round those detected objects so that i're draw it to the original image also if it possible to obtain the corrdinates of those rectangle so i can plot them in the original image 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect white blobs using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805349/how-to-detect-white-blobs-using-opencv)

Comment: this one is using c++, i'm searching for a python solution

Comment: OpenCV is the same, regardless of whether you invoke it from Python or C++.

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't provide code, I will answer without code as well.
You should use findCountours. There is an opencv tutorial that helps you in this exact task: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

`cv2.findContours` returns an array of contours, for each contour in contour you will need to:

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```